# from kivy.app import App error but import kivy is working

Tags: python, kivy

I am getting error when trying from kivy.app import App. 
While import kivy is properly working. It was also prperly installed

```
[INFO              ] [Logger      ] Record log in       
C:\Users\computer\.kivy\logs\kivy_16-02-19_20.txt
[INFO              ] [Kivy        ] v1.9.1
[INFO              ] [Python      ] v2.7.10 (default, May 23 2015, 09:40:32) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)]
[INFO              ] [Factory     ] 179 symbols loaded

 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "C:\Users\computer\Desktop\main.py", line 8, in <module>
     from kivy.app import App
   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\kivy\app.py", line 327, in <module>
     from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\kivy\uix\widget.py", line 219, in <module>
     from kivy.graphics import (
   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\kivy\graphics\__init__.py", line 89, in <module>
     from kivy.graphics.instructions import Callback, Canvas, CanvasBase, \
 ImportError: DLL load failed: The device is not ready.
```

Answer (score 1):

I downloaded whl file from http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/ and installed using pip. After that it started working